# Implement IAuthenticationFilter in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI where I have some controllers.

Now I am going to implement token based security in my web api. 
token is getting generated in our database. 
I want to authenticate actions with this token . 
I am thinking about to Implement it with IAuthenticationFilter. 
But I am not getting how I can do it.

any help here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can flow this topic to implement your filter.

```
public class TokenAuthenticate : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
    {

        public bool AllowMultiple
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                IAuthService _authService = context.ActionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration
                                  .DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IAuthService)) as IAuthService;

                HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;
                AuthenticationHeaderValue authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;

                if (authorization == null)
                {
                    context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Missing autorization header", request);
                    return;
                }
                if (authorization.Scheme != "Bearer")
                {
                    context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid autorization scheme", request);
                    return;
                }
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.Parameter))
                {
                    context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Missing Token", request);
                    return;
                }

                Boolean correctToken = await _authService.ValidateTokenAsync(authorization.Parameter);
                if(!correctToken)
                    context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid Token", request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Exception: \n" + ex.Message, context.Request);
            }
        }

    }
```

https://blog.zaven.co/user-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-rsa-jwt-tokens-part-4/

Comment: If I use VS individual account authentication template, should I not implement IAuthenticationFilter?